# Метод с параметрами и потоки

Tags: c#, многопоточность

К примеру этот фрагмент кода проделывает 5000 тысяч итераций(при интервале frc=0 до frc1=50)

```
 for (double fr = frc; fr <= frc1; fr += shag)
            {                             
              double resulting = (1 / (2 * Math.PI)) * integration.Calculate(angularFrequency => GetSpectralDensityOfAmplitude(GetSpectralDensity(U, angularFrequency, T)) * Math.Cos(angularFrequency * t), 0, frc1);
              list1.Add(fr,resulting);
            }
```

Естественно программа зависает на 2-3 минуты,но выдаёт результат но всё же.
Бывает зависает все 10 минут(зависит сколько введу интервала)

И хотелось бы чтобы этого зависания не было.
Мои первые попытки закинуть метод в поток не увенчались успехом

```
 Thread thd = new Thread(drawgraph(U,T,frc,frc1,frequency,shag));
                thd.Start();
                thd.Join();
```

В теории написано что метод,который нужно вызвать в потоке должен быть без аргументов и параметров,должен быть типа void и не возвращать ничего

Проблема в том что мои метод где этот void но в нём параметры,без них никак нельзя
Как можно поступить в моём случае?

2 процедуры выполняются в общей сложности 1 минут 10 секунд(если ввести минимальные параметры типа 0 и 50)

Если ввести большие параметры к примеру -100 до 100 то программа зависает на 5 минут.

Большинство теории которую я прочитал,предлагают работу с методами типа void но там нету параметров,а в моём есть и без них никуда

И поэтому интересно,возможно ли каким-то образом метод с параметрами вложить в поток?

Comment: `Join` ждет завершения потока, поэтому логично, что ничего от такой записи не поменяется.

Comment: Вы уже применяли замыкания для вычислений - что вам мешает сделать то же самое для потока?..

Comment: @alexout я это исправлю, но как быть с методом у которого есть параметры?

Comment: @PavelMayorov в этом случае не помогает по той причине что у меня 2 графика считываются и итого выходит несколько тысяч итераций

Comment: @beginner вы несете бред. Как количество итераций мешает вам создать поток?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov,если вам нечего ответить по вопросу это ваше право.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите.

Вы должны отделить вычисления от UI-кода. UI-код обязательно должен выполняться в главном потоке, а вот вычисления вполне можно выгрузить в фоновый поток.

Затем, прямое использование потоков — не самая лучшая идея. На текущий момент гораздо лучше использовать async/await.

При этом ваш код будет таким (условно):

```
var data = await Task.Run(() => ComputeData(parameters));
DisplayData(data);
```

Методы, понятно, не обязательно должны так называться.

Ну и ваша процедура, внутри которой вы пользуетесь этим кодом, должна быть async-процедурой. (Мне кажется, вам имеет смысл почитать про это, либо здесь на сайте, либо в интернете. Информации об async/await очень много.)

---

Теперь ещё два слова по поводу того, почему код

```
Thread thd = new Thread(drawgraph(U,T,frc,frc1,frequency,shag));
thd.Start();
thd.Join();
```

не работал.

Во-первых, в конструктор `Thread` нужно передавать функцию (или делегат) без параметров. А `drawgraph(U,T,frc,frc1,frequency,shag)` — это не функция, это *значение*, являющееся результатом вызова функции. С этим бороться просто:

```
() => drawgraph(U,T,frc,frc1,frequency,shag)
```

представляет собой лямбду, «упаковывающую» нужное вычисление в функцию (делегат) без параметров.

Во-вторых (и это серьёзнее), проблема с `thd.Join()`. В этой точке ваш главный поток просто заблокируется и будет дожидаться, пока фоновый поток отработает. То есть это не приносит никакой выгоды по сравнению с выполнением кода в том же потоке: всё равно на всё время вычислений поток блокирован! Решение с `await` не имеет в этой точке проблем.